# How to pass Model to a Controller from a confirm Dialog written with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a HTML page which has a model as follows:

```
@model ViewModel.Ekranlar.ModelVM
```

I call a Confirm Dialog written with JavaScript in the html page as in the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".confirmDialog").on("click", function (e) {
            // e.preventDefault(); use this or return false
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 170,
                width: 350,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        window.location = url;
                    }, "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    }); </script>
```

And the controller is as in the following:

```
public ActionResult DUDBaskaniBuro2GidenIptal(ModelVM model)
```

How can I pass `ModelVM` model to the Action in the controller?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but `return View(model)` in the controller is the generally accepted way.

Answer (score 0):

Though not sure if you are using jquery modal or your custom one, but:

1) If you want to do full page postback, you may make the 'OK' button a 'submit' button type so that on click it will postback to the url mentioned in the form tag.

```
<input type="submit" value="OK" .../>
```

2) If you want to do partial postback, you may use something like:

```
"OK": function () {
        $.post('@Url.Action("ActionMethod","ControllerName")', 
                <captured values via jquery/javascript as json>, //E.g. {"Id":1,"Name":"My Name"}
                function(data){ 
                         //Code you want to do here
                          $(this).dialog("close");   //Just an example
                          window.location = data.url; //Just an example
                 });

}
```

Comment: @Hasanİslam : Did either of the approach provide help to solve your problem?